# Why Can't I Upload APK To Google PLay?

Tags: android, google-play

Strange issue just started happening! I submitted an app to android store just fine about 10 minutes ago, I have just come to submit a different app and now google won't let me select the APK file from the open dialog and if I drag and drop it says invalid file type. It also does the same thing if I try a new release on the app i previously submitted without an issue.

In my screenshot attached you can see the APK is greyed out and I can't select it?

[image]

Comment: Can you drag and drop the apk to it?

Comment: AFAIK, since 1st August onwards you have to upload OBB for the first time upload but you can still upload APK for existing releases. More: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html?m=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to upload AAB (Android app bundle).

[Starting in August 2021](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html), developers wanting to publish new Android apps on the Google Play Store will have to change how those apps are packaged together: Rather than the traditional APK (Android application package) format that has been in place for years, software makers are going to be required to use the AAB (Android app bundle) framework instead.

Comment: Right ok, do you have any sources on how to build these new files with ionic cordova?

Comment: @GELK https://medium.com/swlh/generating-an-android-app-bundle-from-your-ionic-app-without-android-studio-5bc3acaf4528